# Finding the roots of equation system

Tags: r, equation, nonlinear-functions

I would like to use `multiroot` command in the `rootSolve` package to find b and m. 
The code is given below. 
I tried different starting values but the result was either `NaN` or `NaNs produced`.

```
n <- 23
model <- function(theta){  
  b <- theta[1]
  m <- theta[2] 
  power <- exp(-(x-m)*b)
  a <- -n/sum(log(1-power))
  betat <- apply(x,1,function(x) (x-m)*power/(1-power))
  mut <- apply(x,1, function(x) power/(1-power))
  F1 <- n/b-sum(x)+n*m+(a-1)*sum(betat)
  F2 <- n*b-b*(a-1)*sum(mut)
  c(F1=F1,F2=F2)
}
multiroot(f = model, start = c(.5, .5))
```

So can someone explain me where the mistake is, please?

Comment: Are you sure that there is a solution? Beside of this nonlinear problems are in general hard. They could be very sensible regarding to the starting values, the convergence criteria ...

Comment: I added system and reported solution

Comment: there is a mistake in publication?

Comment: if i assume the reported values isn't known. how can i solve the equation system correcly?

Comment: A couple of first impressions:

1. $u$ should have the subscript $i$, based on $x_i$ being in the formula. This would mean that you wouldn't want apply for the calculation of `betat` and `mut` if you take `x` to be a vector rather than a matrix.
2. You are going to have problems with numerical stability as $u$ approaches 1. equivalent to $x-m$ or $b$ approaching 0

Can you rewrite the equation at all to try to resolve that, I'm thinking log sum exp trick might be useful here?

Comment: I added the equations from the original paper. a=alpha, b=beta, m=mu... alpha can be expressed in terms of beta and mu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(rootSolve)
x<- c(17.88,28.92,33,41.52,42.12,45.6,48.40,51.84,51.96,54.12,55.56,67.80,
  68.64,68.64,68.88,84.12,93.12, 98.64,105.12,105.84,127.92,128.04,173.4)
n <- length(x)

model <- function(theta){  
  b <- theta[1]
  m <- theta[2] 
  power <- exp(-(x-m)*b)
  a <- -n/sum(log(1-power))
  F1 <- n/b-sum(x-m) + (a-1)*sum((x-m)*power/(1-power))
  F2 <- n*b - b*(a-1)*sum(power/(1-power))
  c(F1=F1,F2=F2)
}
# model(c(b = 0.031, m = 4.748))
multiroot(f = model, start = c(.03, 5))
```

so the result is:

```
> multiroot(f = model, start = c(.03, 5))
$root
[1] 0.03140027 4.55976021

$f.root
           F1            F2 
-2.046363e-12 -6.217249e-15 

$iter
[1] 5

$estim.precis
[1] 1.02629e-12
```

Comment: thanks. but there is still a problem. small changes in starting values is giving NaN's. Actually i checked this results and compare them with original paper's. this results are better than those. But starting values are really a big problem.

Comment: If nothing other helps one has to do a grid-search for the starting values.